# Override customer sales order history template not working

Tags: magento2, layout-update, override-block, custom-template

I want to override sales order history for customer in frontend like this:

**app/code/Test/SuccessPage/view/frontend/layout/sales_order_history.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
          <referenceBlock name="sales.order.history.extra.containe">
              <action method="setTemplate">
                  <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Test_SuccessPage::order/history.phtml
              </action>
          </referenceBlock>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**app/code/Test/SuccessPage/view/frontend/templates/order/history.phtml**

```
<h1> This is a test page </h1>
```

unfortunately the above code doesnt work at all, it still load the vendor history.phtml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following way:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="sales.order.history">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Test_SuccessPage::order/history.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: how to set custom block class for this? or override the default block here?

Comment: @jafarpinjar you can overwrite bock class using preference.

Comment: yes i am using like that, this is the issue
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/246603/override-sales-order-history-issue-in-magento2?

Comment: unfortunately this didn't work

Comment: @AshwaniShukla make sure your module load after Magento_Sales module

Comment: @SohelRana yes it is. changed `$_template` variable and it worked like charm.