# How to override or how to edit core files in magento 2.2[basically i need to one more column in My Account->My orders)

Tags: magento2.2.6

Please suggest me how to edit core files in magento 2.2 
I need add a one more column in My Account->My orders section [Customers order details].[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can get reference from this layout file.

vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/layout/sales_order_history.xml

And for add new columns.

vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/order/history.phtml

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i dont want to edit in core files and I need to edit in extra created modules(app/code/namespace/modules), please suggest me, i am newbe to magento 2.2.6

Comment: You can refer this link for override history.phtml https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/195217/override-customer-sales-order-history-template-not-working#